# form validation not working properly

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

i am validating a form with jquery and having some problems.
jquery validation code:

```
$(function(){
    var form = $('#contactus');
    var name = $('#name');
    var nameInfo = $('#nameInfo');
    var email = $('#email'); 
    var emailInfo = $('#emailInfo');
    var phone = $('#phone');
    var phoneInfo = $('#phoneInfo');
    var msg = $('#message');
    var msgInfo = $('#messageInfo');
    var reg=/^[a-zA-Z. ]+$/;
    var mail=/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/; 





    function validateName()
    {
        if(name.val()=='')
        {
            name.addClass('error');
            nameInfo.text('Please fill up your full Name');
            nameInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else if(reg.test(name)==false){
            name.addClass('error');
            nameInfo.text('Only letters are allowed');
            nameInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            name.removeClass('error');
            nameInfo.text('');
            nameInfo.removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateEmail()
    {
        if(email.val()=='')
        {
            email.addClass('error');
            emailInfo.text('Please fill in your Valid Email');
            emailInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else if(mail.test(email)==false){
            email.addClass('error');
            emailInfo.text('Invalid Email');
            emailInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            email.removeClass('error');
            emailInfo.removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validatePhone()
    {
        if(phone.val()=='')
        {
            phone.addClass('error');
            phoneInfo.text('Please fill in your Phone number');
            phoneInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else if(isNaN(phone)){
            phone.addClass('error');
            phoneInfo.text('Please fill in your Phone number');
            phoneInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            phone.removeClass('error');
            phoneInfo.removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateMsg(){
        if(msg.val()=='')
        {
            msg.addClass('error');
            msgInfo.text('Please enter your Message');
            msgInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else if(msg.val().length<10){
            msg.addClass('error');
            msgInfo.text('Please enter at least 10 words');
            msgInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            msg.removeClass('error');
            msgInfo.removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*name.blur(validateName);
    email.blur(validateEmail);
    phone.blur(validatePhone);
    msg.blur(validateMsg);*/

    name.keyup(validateName);
    email.keyup(validateEmail);
    phone.keyup(validatePhone);
    msg.keyup(validateMsg);

    form.submit(function(){
        if(validateName() ,validateEmail() , validatePhone(), validateMsg() ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    })
})
```

and php form code is:

```
<form name="contactus"  id="contactus" action="" method="post">
        <ul class="form_field">
            <li><label>Your Name :</label>
                <input class="form_input" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>" />
                <span id="nameInfo"></span>
            </li>
            <li><label>Email Address :</label>
                <input class="form_input" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>" />
                <span id="emailInfo"></span>
            </li>
            <li><label>Phone Number :</label>
                <input class="form_input" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone'];?>" />
                <span id="phoneInfo"></span>
            </li>
            <li><label>Your Message:</label>
                <textarea class="form_input" name="message" id="message"><?php echo $_POST['message'];?></textarea>
                <span id="messageInfo"></span>
            </li>
            <li><?php echo recaptcha(); ?></li>
            <li><label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" class="submit_btn" value="Submit"  name="submit"/></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

problem is second condition isn't validated properly for any of the form elements. Though null condition is succeded 2nd condition isn't. am i doing any wrong.any help/suggestions is welcome. thanks a lot.

Comment: `var reg=/^[a-zA-Z. ]+$/;` should be `var reg=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;`

Comment: hab already tried it..but to no avail..:(

Comment: Do you see any errors on console ?

Comment: no not single error displayed on cosole...

Comment: What did you mean by `second condition` and which function did you mean `validateName` or `validateEmail` ?

Comment: for each validate function i have included 2 conditions, 1st one being null condition which works perfectly fine and 2nd condition being "no number allowed for name", "valid email for email", "only number for phone" which doesn't work at all.

Comment: `var reg=/^[a-zA-Z. ]+$/;` should be `var reg=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;` to allow `alphanumeric` values but I still didn't understand what did you  mean by `valid email for email`

Comment: @Sheikh Heera sorry for the late response ... but i don't want number in my name. as i am validating this for college site i don't want numeric character in my name and as for valid email issue i want abc_xyz@xxx.com as valid email and not something like abc@xyz_xxx.co or anything like that

Answer (score 0):

> i don't want numeric character in my name and as for valid email issue
>   i want abc_xyz@xxx.com as valid email and not something like
>   abc@xyz_xxx.co or anything like that

```
var reg=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
var mail=/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$/;
```

Also modify your functions to

```
function validateName()
{
    var val=name.val();
    if(!reg.test(val))
    {
        if(val.length > 0) nameInfo.text('Only letters are allowed');
        else nameInfo.text('Please fill up your full Name');
        name.addClass('error');
        nameInfo.addClass('error');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        name.removeClass('error');
        nameInfo.text('');
        nameInfo.removeClass('error');
        return true;
    }
}

function validateEmail()
{
    var val=email.val();
    if(!mail.test(val))
    {
        if(val.length > 0) emailInfo.text('Invalid Email');
        else emailInfo.text('Please fill in your Valid Email');
        email.addClass('error');
        emailInfo.addClass('error');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        email.removeClass('error');
        emailInfo.removeClass('error');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also in your `validatePhone() function` change

```
else if(isNaN(phone));
```

to

```
else if(isNaN(phone.val()));
```

[**Here is a test of regular Expression**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cNWWC/1/).

Comment: thank you @ Sheikh Heera .... got it right all now but i am still confused why my previous code wasn't working. can you make me clear and yes "!val.test(reg)" returned error as val.test isn't a function and to correct it i used "!reg.test(val)". it worked. so i am confused why does your code didn't work for me.have you any idea and yess THANKS for the solution.

Comment: One common mistake you made `reg.test(name)` name is hare the reference of the input box that is an object but not value of that input box.

Comment: oh so simple a mistake and i wasn't getting it. thank you so much @Sheikh Heera

Answer (score 0):

correct code for my question:

```
    $(function(){

    var form = $('#contactus');
    var name = $('#name');
    var nameInfo = $('#nameInfo');
    var email = $('#email'); 
    var emailInfo = $('#emailInfo');
    var phone = $('#phone');
    var phoneInfo = $('#phoneInfo');
    var msg = $('#message');
    var msgInfo = $('#messageInfo');
    var reg=/^[a-zA-Z. ]+$/;
    var mail=/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/; 





    function validateName()
    { 
        if(name.val()=='')
        {
            name.addClass('error');
            nameInfo.text('Please fill up your full Name');
            nameInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else if(!reg.test(name.val())){
            name.addClass('error');
            nameInfo.text('Only letters are allowed');
            nameInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            name.removeClass('error');
            nameInfo.text('');
            nameInfo.removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateEmail()
    { 
        if(email.val()=='')
        {
            email.addClass('error');
            emailInfo.text('Please fill in your Valid Email');
            emailInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else if(!mail.test(email.val())){
            email.addClass('error');
            emailInfo.text('Invalid Email');
            emailInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            email.removeClass('error');
            emailInfo.text("");
            emailInfo.removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validatePhone()
    { 
        if(phone.val()=='')
        {
            phone.addClass('error');
            phoneInfo.text('Please fill in your Phone number');
            phoneInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else if(isNaN(phone.val())){
            phone.addClass('error');
            phoneInfo.text('Please fill in your correct number');
            phoneInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            phone.removeClass('error');
            phoneInfo.text("");
            phoneInfo.removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    }
    function validateMsg(){
        if(msg.val()=='')
        {
            msg.addClass('error');
            msgInfo.text('Please enter your Message');
            msgInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else if(msg.val().length<10){
            msg.addClass('error');
            msgInfo.text('Please enter at least 10 words');
            msgInfo.addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            msg.removeClass('error');
            msgInfo.text("");
            msgInfo.removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
    }

    name.blur(validateName);
    email.blur(validateEmail);
    phone.blur(validatePhone);
    msg.blur(validateMsg);

    name.keyup(validateName);
    email.keyup(validateEmail);
    phone.keyup(validatePhone);
    msg.keyup(validateMsg);

    form.submit(function(){
        if(validateName() ,validateEmail() , validatePhone(), validateMsg() ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    })
})
```